# Trouble getting my loop output to format properly

Tags: java, format

I'm getting my loop to print the integers 1-7 in vertical order.
So like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

That part works fine. Now I also need it to print next to it if the integer is divisible by 3. My code is as follows

```
for (int n = 1; n < 8; n++){
        System.out.println(n );
        if (n % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print("divides evenly into 3");
        }
    }
```

Now my output looks like

```
1
2
3
divides evenly into 34
5
6
divides evenly into 37
```

I need the divides evenly part to be on the same line as 3 and 6. Not the line after. Anyone have any insight as to what I'm writing wrong here in my code?
I am using Java.

Comment: `println` is a print line so look at that for a start.

Comment: I changed it to print() and that still does not fix the problem because I need them to each be on their own line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `else` condition:

```
for (int n = 1; n < 8; n++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(n + " divides evenly into 3");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I did not try this!

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer is fine; here's an slight variation that avoids repeating the printing of `n`:

```
for (int n = 1; n < 8; n++) {
    // Using print instead of println doesn't insert the newline.
    System.out.print(n);
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print(" divides evenly into 3");
    }
    // When there's nothing more to print on the line, now add the
    // newline.
    System.out.println();
}
```